# AttributeError: probability estimates are not available for loss='hinge'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect',CountVectorizer(decode_error='ignore')),
                      ('tfidf',TfidfTransformer()),
                      ('clf',SGDClassifier(loss = 'hinge',penalty = 'elasticnet',alpha = 1e-3,n_iter = 10, random_state = 40))])

text_clf = text_clf.fit(trainDocs+valDocs,np.array(trainLabels+valLabels))
predicted = text_clf.predict_proba(testDocs)
```

How can I get the predicted probability of every test sample? Thanks!

Comment: As the error message says, you can't get probabilities if you use the hinge loss function.  Use a different one instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, why can svm.svc(probability = True)) get the probability? I know that the loss of svm is hinge. In my imbalance task, SGDClassifier with hinge loss is the best. Therefore, I want to get the probability of this model. If possible, would you tell me how to modify some code to get the probability? Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't know the mathematical details of why one model can get the probability and one can't, but it's not super surprising since SVM and SGD are totally different algorithms.  You could try asking the scikit people (e.g., in a github issue or on their mailing list) how to get SGD probabilities with hinge loss, but (assuming it is possible at all), it's unlikely to be a simple task, or they would have already done it.

Answer (score 17):

`SGDClassifier(loss = 'hinge')` does not have probability by default.

You have to pass `SGDclassifier(loss = 'hinge')` to `CalibratedClassifierCV()` which will calculate the probability values of `SGDclassifier(loss = 'hinge')`.

```
lr = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge',alpha=best_alpha,class_weight='balanced')
clf =lr.fit(X_tr, y_train)
calibrator = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf, cv='prefit')
model=calibrator.fit(X_tr, y_train)

y_train_pred = model.predict_proba(X_tr)
y_test_pred = model.predict_proba(X_te)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `decision_function` instead of `predict_proba` to get the predicted values.